# Kubectl get only nodes with status ready

Tags: kubernetes

I want to get the list of active nodes using kubectl.
Is there a flag to do this. At the moment,
I am just running

kubectl get node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
kubectl get nodes | grep Ready
```

or you can do this

```
JSONPATH='{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}:{range @.status.conditions[*]} 
{@.type}={@.status};{end}{end}' \
&& kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath="$JSONPATH" | grep "Ready=True"
```